# ASIhttprequest sometimes timeout in wifi, iOS6, and it's OK after rebooting iphone

Tags: iphone, ios6, wifi, asihttprequest

I'm using ASIhttprequest, it works fine for most cases.
    However, some customers and I encounter timeout in some rare cases. (It may happen 3~5 times for daily uses in 3 monthes.) Moreover, I already set timeout to 30s. And I also set the timeout to 130s when this problem happens, but it doesn't help.

When it happens, I can't upload image to my http server for about 200KB JPEG file, 
    but 100 bytes text uploading is OK, and other functions(post) works fine.

My platform is iphone4, iOS6, wifi.
    Most weird thing is it's OK when I switching network to 3G, and fail for wifi.
    However, safari always works well on the same phone.

Another ipad on iOS5 seems always OK for both wifi and 3G.

I searched via google, but I can't get resolved method.
   Is it apple iOS6's bug or bugs for ASIhttprequests?

How could I solve it? ASIhttpreqeust stopped updating...
   Is MKNetworkKit reliable ?

Thank you.

Comment: Try `AFNetworking` instead: https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking

Comment: I'm afraid that's a deprecated library

Answer (score 0):

No it cannot be a bug. I have been using ASI for few years without any issue. Yes it can fail for any scenario based on your network stability. Just try to increase the timeout of the request. Sometimes it happens because server throws errors. Better you log errors in requestFailed called backs and see.

Follow this to set timeout for all ASI requests.

```
[ASIHTTPRequest setDefaultTimeOutSeconds:10];
```

Follow this to set timeout for specific ASI request.

```
asiRequest.timeOutSeconds = 20;
```

As ASI is now deprecated you may consider moving to AFNetworking or RestKit or any other framework. Using this based on the reachability class you can easily capture network unavailability.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I already set timeout to 130s to test if too short timeout, but it still fails. I think it's weird for my problem. 3G works, but wifi fails. The error shows timeout instead of instant feedback for network unavailable. Moreover, iPad iOS5.1 works, but iphone with iOS6 fails. it only happens serval times for 90 days usage. So, it's hard to debug...I just wonder if iOS6 has some wifi bug, so that ASIhttprequest hit the bugs. Moreover, small data is OK, but uploading 200KB jpeg fails. I have no idea on this.